# Inject repository if other extension is loaded

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I want to check if **another extension** is loaded and only then inject a repository.

```
/**
 * Inject publication repository from other extension
 *
 * @param \Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Repository\PublicationRepository $publicationRepository
 */
public function injectPublicationRepository(\Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Repository\PublicationRepositorysitory $publicationRepository)
{
    if (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::isLoaded('extension_name')) {
        $this->publicationRepository = $publicationRepository;
    }
}
```

This does not work. In frontend I got an exception:

```
Class Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Repository\PublicationRepositorysitory does not exist. Reflection failed.
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that youre checking for the extension inside the inject function but the inject function is getting called from outside with the repo as a param already. That means your repo instance is beign created _ahead_ of your check. Therefore you receive that error. Maybe a solution would be to not use DI for this but get your repo "by hand" using the ObjectManager class _after_ you check for the extension to be loaded.

Comment: If the extension is not installed, you cannot use \Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Repository\PublicationRepositorysitory because the runtime autoload doesn't find the class, but you can use a generic class like TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository.